# ListView Does Not save the edited record

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am using an ASP.net 4.5 ListView using Data Entity to populate the control
When I edit a record using the C# code below it does not save the changes.  The code compiles without any errors and if I step through the code it pulls the record I am editing it just will not save the changes.  Here is the code:

```
    public void ListView1_UpdateItem(int LinkAnalysisID)
    {
        LinkAnalysis.LinkAnalysi item = null;
        using (LAEntities db = new LAEntities())
        {
            // Load the item here, e.g. item = MyDataLayer.Find(id);
            item = db.LinkAnalysis.SingleOrDefault(uu => uu.LinkAnalysisId == LinkAnalysisID);

        if (item == null)
        {
            // The item wasn't found
            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", LinkAnalysisID));
            return;
        }
        TryUpdateModel(item);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Save changes here, e.g. MyDataLayer.SaveChanges();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

After further research I have edited my code to what it shown below.

```
     public void ListView1_UpdateItem(int LinkAnalysisID)
    {
        LinkAnalysis.LinkAnalysi item = null;
        using (LAEntities db = new LAEntities())
        {
            // Load the item here, e.g. item = MyDataLayer.Find(id);
            item = db.LinkAnalysis.Find(LinkAnalysisID);
            //item = db.LinkAnalysis.SingleOrDefault(uu => uu.LinkAnalysisId == LinkAnalysisID);

        if (item == null)
        {
            // The item wasn't found
            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", LinkAnalysisID));
            return;
        }
        TryUpdateModel(item);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Save changes here, e.g. MyDataLayer.SaveChanges();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        }
    }
```

I still get the same results the code runs but the changes are not saved to the database.

Comment: `TryUpdateModel(item);` does this method actually add anything .. I do not see any where where you are doing `db.SomeEntity.Add` method

Comment: Set a breakpoint on TryUpdateModel. Execute it and check whether your EntityState says Changed. In addition, check whether it passes ModelState.IsValid. If both don't happen, you won't see an update.

Comment: And assuming you changed something on the page, so it posts a change. That's the third requirement for your update to succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your response MethodMan the method is suppose to edit the record.  The method executes and I can view the data and the ModelState validates to true.  The changes to the records are not written to the data base.  Interesting situation I am trying to use this code in a Listview, the same code works fine if I use it in a Gridview.

Comment: Dacker thanks for your comments as well.  I have set the breakpoint and cycled thru the code the ModelSate does check as valid.